# How to make query in postgresql which will find all records which are started more than 6 hours?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

How to make query in postgresql which will find all records which are started more than 6 hours ago?

In my table I have a column which stores utc time of last time used in milliseconds (long integer).

```
SELECT *
FROM exams
WHERE started < HERE_I_NEED_UTC_IN_MILLISECONDS - 6 * 60 * 1000 * 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from exams
where started < extract(epoch from (current_timestamp - interval '6' hour))
```